# closure error when connecting UI with logic Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I need to connect UI with the module.

Error: Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Bool'

**Controller Code:**

```
private func connectLogicView() {
    screenView.handlePlayPauseButton(sender: screenView.playPauseButton) { () -> Bool in

        obj.playPause(queue: .global()) { //Error here
            if self.obj.getPlayer().timeControlStatus != .paused {
                return true
            } else if self.obj.getPlayer().timeControlStatus == .paused {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Module code:**

```
public func playPause(queue: DispatchQueue, completion: @escaping ()->Void){
    if player.timeControlStatus == .playing {
        player.pause()
    } else {
        player.play()
    }
    queue.async {
        completion()
    }
}
```

**UI code:**

```
func handlePlayPauseButton(sender: UIButton, completion: () -> Bool) {
    if completion() == true {
        sender.setTitle("pause", for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.setTitle("play", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

If you can show a better way, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya what do you mean?

Comment: You have make your code too confusing why you required `playPause(queue: DispatchQueue`  to be async ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya hmm, I was writing code on the go. While making a unit test I was running into some problems and making closure run on queue async solved my issue. I've just removed queue part, now completion is running without queue block.

Comment: yes That was unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`playPause` method don't have anything in `completion` block but

```
 obj.playPause(queue: .global()) { 
        if self.obj.getPlayer().timeControlStatus != .paused {
            return true // NO NEED FOR THIS LINE
        } else if self.obj.getPlayer().timeControlStatus == .paused {
            return false  // NO NEED FOR THIS LINE
        }
   }
```

You are returning true or false  remove that and your code will run fine

Comment: It solved my issue. I realized while connecting to modules I was calling play method instead of comparing states. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Prashant Tukadiya said the code seems to be little bit tricky/complex. 
Easy way would be something similar to below

```
func playPause(queue: DispatchQueue, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
   let someOtherCondition: Bool = false
   var returnAnswer: Bool = false
   if someOtherCondition {
       print("player paused")
       returnAnswer = true
   } else {
       print("player play")
   }
   queue.async {
       completion(returnAnswer)
   }
}

func connectLogicView() {
   let aSampleButton: UIButton = UIButton.init()
   playPause(queue: .global()) { (isPlaying) in
       if isPlaying {
           aSampleButton.setTitle("pause", for: .normal)
       } else {
           aSampleButton.setTitle("play", for: .normal)
       }
   }
}
```